# Python API - Panel INSTANCED Flag

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, panel

I have 16 collections of properties that I would like to display in a list of panels. It seems that the old way to do this is to write and register a new class for each panel, even though they are all identical save for the data. I see now in the documentation that there is an `INSTANCED` option for panels, which seems to indicate that I can create multiple panels from the same class, but I cannot find any example or explanation of how to use it. Any help?

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Panel.html

Comment: The constraints UI is an example. `properties_constraint.py`