# How to create grip for rearranging UI?

Tags: python, add-on

I am interested in finding a way of creating this kind of UI for moving and adjusting order of slots? I am specifically looking for a way to adjust order of String Properties?

[image]

Comment: Been considering answering what I know so far into this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/193824/python-api-panel-instanced-flag would recommend looking at constraints UI code.  One "master" panel class is used as mix in for  all constraints (modifiers same)  `bl_options = {'INSTANCED', 'HEADER_LAYOUT_EXPAND', 'DRAW_BOX'}`  The draw box option enables dragging and dropping of panels.. but to outside its parent into another.   Each type of constraint is given its own class that merely points its draw to the specific draw of the "master".  An instance of the panel is made for each

Comment: constraint of the objects constraints, and the panel instances `self.custom_data` property is set to the constraint.  The layout is drawn with `UILayout.template_constraint` (or some such)  How this is wired up, and whether it is available via python. on a collection of our choosing,  yet I am not sure.